# Alternative to pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am newbie in sql language and need some help to rearrange data.

(I am working with sql server 2008)

I have this table (substitute) :

```
iteid | substitutedescr  |  substitutecode
37664 | EANCUTIE3        |  14902778788926
37664 | EAN1             |  4902778788929
37664 | EANCUTIE1        |  4902778931653
37664 | EANCUTIE2        |  4902778931738
```

and i want a select to look like this:

```
iteid   EAN1            EANCUTIE1           EANCUTIE2       EANCUTIE3
37664                                                       14902778788926
37664   4902778788929           
37664                   4902778931653       
37664                                       4902778931738
```

I tried to use pivot:

```
select *
from (
           select iteid as [ID], substitutedescr as [descr], substitutecode     as [Values]
           from substitute) as s
PIVOT
(
SUM(SUBSTITUTECODE)
FOR [DESCR] in ( ean1, ean2, ean3, eancutie1, eancutie2, eancutie3) 
) as pvt
```

But seems that i need to set the compatibility level to a higher value in order to activate pivot function.

I have other alternative to gain this result ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `pivot` for this, just `case`:

```
select iteid,
       (case when substitutedescr = 'EAN1' then substitutecode end) as EAN1,
       (case when substitutedescr = 'EANCUTIE1' then substitutecode end) as EANCUTIE1,
       (case when substitutedescr = 'EANCUTIE2' then substitutecode end) as EANCUTIE2,
       (case when substitutedescr = 'EANCUTIE3' then substitutecode end) as EANCUTIE3
from substitute;
```

You would want `pivot` (or aggregation) if you wanted one row per `iteid` with all the values on that row.  For instance:

```
select iteid,
       max(case when substitutedescr = 'EAN1' then substitutecode end) as EAN1,
       max(case when substitutedescr = 'EANCUTIE1' then substitutecode end) as EANCUTIE1,
       max(case when substitutedescr = 'EANCUTIE2' then substitutecode end) as EANCUTIE2,
       max(case when substitutedescr = 'EANCUTIE3' then substitutecode end) as EANCUTIE3
from substitute
group by iteid;
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer :D Solved my problem.